# How to make the if else here?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
%include "asm_io.asm"
global main

    segment .data
        msg1 : db "somme-nous samedi?",10,0
        msg2 : db "Bonne weekend",10,0
        msg3 : db "Bonne journee",10,0
    segment .bss
    
    segment .text

main :

    mov eax,msg1
    call print_string
    
    call read_int
    
    cmp eax,1
    je one
    
    cmp eax,0
    je two
    
    jmp here
    
    one :
        mov eax,msg2
        call print_string
        jmp here
    
    two :
        mov eax,msg3
        call print_string
    
    here :
        mov ebx,0
        mov eax,1
                int 0x80
```

How to make the if else here to print "bonne journee" if the value entered  is 0 and "bonne weekend" if it's 1?

Comment: This example seems like it does exactly what you are asking. What is your question? How does the example's behaviour differ from what you want?

Comment: when assemblying the program , it doesn't works

Comment: Be more specific.

Comment: Yeah , it works finally

Comment: How about making a loop to enter only "1" or "0" without any other number ??